# How show only a specific number of lines with the Wrap widget?

Tags: flutter

I have a Wrap widget that shows some a maximum of 10 tags (chips), default directions (left to right and up to down). What I need is to show only 3 lines of this Wrap widget, but as sometimes the 10 items take 4 lines, I put the Wrap inside a SizedBox and tried to match the Box's height as best as possible based on the size config of the content of the Wrap. But it's not perfect, it shows well in some screens but in others it's either too short or too large (cutting the third row, or cutting the fourth row if there is one).

Is there a widget that would allow me to resize the Wrap dynamically to always show only 3 rows, independent from the screen and font sizes?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could use richText widget and give it a maxLines of 3.

> maxLines → int? An optional maximum number of lines for the text to
> span, ***wrapping*** if necessary. If the text exceeds the given number of
> lines, it will be truncated according to overflow. [...] final

```
RichText(
  maxLines: 3,
  text: TextSpan(
    text: 'Hello ',
    style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
    children: const <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: 'bold', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      TextSpan(text: ' world!'),
    ],
  ),
)
```

You can then add your tags inside the children.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html